# zsh: "ls -S" not working in the Utilities folder

Tags: ls

I am learning some basic UNIX commands these days. Today was `ls`. I wanted to sort my results by size.

- I tried `ls -lS /Applications/Utilities` the results were not sorted.
- I tried `ls -lS ~/Downloads` the results were sorted.

Any idea why? Why can't I sort the results of a specific folder?

Comment: How are you intending to sort?  `-S` sorts by size not by name.  `ls -l` should sort roughly alphabetically as is.

Comment: I apparently asked in the same instruction to sort my results by size and by name which of course is impossible. I tried `ls -S /Utilities`. The results were sorted alphabetically not by size. I have tried `ls -S ~/Documents` and the results were sorted by size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Applications/Utilities` smells like macOS. IIRC that directory on macOS typically contains directories, not regular files.

Directories are special types of files that contain a list of file names in some opaque format. The size of directory files usually grows with the number of files in them, but not always. For instance, I don't know about macOS file systems, but on many others, space occupied by a directory entry is usually not reclaimed when it is removed (when the corresponding file is unlinked from the directory).

Directory files are also often allocated in chunks. I suspect all those directories have the same size as they contain few entries so are only one chunk (maybe something like 4KiB), which would explain why `ls` sorts them by name (as a way to resolve ties).

All in all, the size of directories is not really relevant.

If you wanted to sort the list of directories based on the cumulative disk usage of all the files in them (recursively), you would do:

```
du -ks /Application/Utilities/* | sort -n
```

(assuming those directory names don't contain newline characters).

Comment: I red folders were kinda special in some tutorials but your explanation makes everything clearer in my mind. Thank you for your very informative answer!